# Disable multiple selects with a checkbox

Tags: javascript

My code is a mess, sorry about that.

The JS works but only for the first select; I want the user to input a time, but if the user does not work that day, I want to disable the four select boxes. Unfortunately, I don't know where to add the other selects in the JS.

There's another script that fills in the rest of the options for the selects.
The code I have so far:

```js
if (document.getElementById('holiday_check').checked)
    document.getElementById('holiday_time_h1').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

function closed_holiday() {
    if (document.getElementById('holiday_check').checked)
        document.getElementById('holiday_time_h1').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    else
        document.getElementById('holiday_time_h1').removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

```html
<div> 
 <span>Opening Time:</span>
 <select id="holiday_time_h1"><option>00</option></select>
 :
 <select id="holiday_time_m1"><option>00</option></select>
  
 <span>Closing time</span>
 <select id="holiday_time_h2"><option>00</option></select>
 :
 <select id="holiday_time_m2"><option>00</option></select>
  
  <input id="holiday_check" class="check" type="checkbox" onchange="closed_holiday();">Closed</input>
     
</div>
```

Comment: on closed click u want to disable all selectboxes?

Comment: yes but only the 4 mentioned selectboxes since there are 3 other divs that work the same

Comment: can u do like `document.getElementsByTagName('select').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');` ? to hide all boxes?

Comment: wouldn't that hide all of the selectboxes on the page?

Comment: can u use jquery? if yes then you can set class/id to main div tag then $('.divClass select').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); will help u

Comment: thank you, i can use jquery but only to a certain extent, still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this uses jquery's `$.each` to iterate over the arrays.

Also, here I am using wildcards to select all elements that begin with id `holiday_check` and then looping over them and disabling them.

```js
function closed_holiday() {
    if (document.getElementById('holiday_check').checked) {
      var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=holiday_time]');
      
      //Jquery Solution
      //$.each(checkboxes, function() {
      //  this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      //});
      
      for (i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){ 
        checkboxes[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    } else {
      var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=holiday_time]');
      
      //Jquery solution
      //$.each(checkboxes, function() {
      //  this.removeAttribute('disabled');
      //});
      
      for (i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){ 
        checkboxes[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Opening Time:</span>
  <select id="holiday_time_h1">
    <option>00</option>
  </select>
  :
  <select id="holiday_time_m1">
    <option>00</option>
  </select>

  <span>Closing time</span>
  <select id="holiday_time_h2">
    <option>00</option>
  </select>
  :
  <select id="holiday_time_m2">
    <option>00</option>
  </select>

  <input id="holiday_check" class="check" type="checkbox" onchange="closed_holiday();">Closed</input>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i've been trying to do

Answer (score 2):

There is multiple ways to abort this problem.
The most common and abordable way is to loop through each select and disable them one by one.

First, you need to get an array for each select element that you want to disable. You can attach to them the same class; let's say "holiday", then get all of them in an array using the selector [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Once you've done that, you loop through this array of elements and you disable them when the user choose to disable via the checkbox element.

```js
const mySelectElements = document.getElementsByClassName("holiday");
const holidayCheck = document.getElementById("holiday_check");

function closed_holiday(){
  for(let selectElement of mySelectElements){
    if(holidayCheck.checked){
      selectElement.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } 
    else{
      selectElement.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
  }  
}
```

```html
<div> 
 <span>Opening Time:</span>
 <select class="holiday" id="holiday_time_h1"><option>00</option></select>
 :
 <select class="holiday" id="holiday_time_m1"><option>00</option></select>
  
 <span>Closing time</span>
 <select class="holiday" id="holiday_time_h2"><option>00</option></select>
 :
 <select class="holiday" id="holiday_time_m2"><option>00</option></select>
  
  <input id="holiday_check" class="check" type="checkbox" onchange="closed_holiday();">Closed</input>
     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking to disable multiple `<select>` elements at a time, applying a class name to each of them greatly simplifies DOM lookups in your event handler. Note that instead of manipulating the HTML attribute `disabled` you can toggle the `disabled` property, and this is much terser! Finally, consider attaching an event listener to your checkbox in JS as opposed to writing callbacks in HTML.

```js
var selects = document.getElementsByClassName('holiday-select'),
    checkbox = document.getElementById('holiday_check')

function closed_holiday() {
    for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        selects[i].disabled ^= true // toggle
    }
}
  
if (checkbox.checked) {
    closed_holiday()
}
checkbox.addEventListener('change', closed_holiday)
```

```html
<div>
    <span>Opening Time:</span>
    <select id="holiday_time_h1" class="holiday-select"><option>00</option></select>
    :
    <select id="holiday_time_m1" class="holiday-select"><option>00</option></select>
    <span>Closing time</span>
    <select id="holiday_time_h2" class="holiday-select"><option>00</option></select>
    :
    <select id="holiday_time_m2" class="holiday-select"><option>00</option></select>
    <input id="holiday_check" class="check" type="checkbox">Closed</input>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function closed_holiday() {
  if(document.getElementById('holiday_check').checked) {    
    document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach((function(x){ x.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');}))
  }                  
  else {
    document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach((function(x){ x.removeAttribute('disabled');}));
  }              
}
```

```html
<div> 
 <span>Opening Time:</span>
 <select id="holiday_time_h1"><option>00</option></select>
 :
 <select id="holiday_time_m1"><option>00</option></select>
  
 <span>Closing time</span>
 <select id="holiday_time_h2"><option>00</option></select>
 :
 <select id="holiday_time_m2"><option>00</option></select>
  
  <input id="holiday_check" class="check" type="checkbox" onchange="closed_holiday();">Closed
     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily disable and enable by just one line,

```js
if (document.getElementById('holiday_check').checked)
  document.getElementById('holiday_time_h1').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

$('#holiday_check').on('change', function() {
  if (document.getElementById('holiday_check').checked) {
    document.getElementById('holiday_time_h1').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.Timesheet select').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //ADDED LINE
  } else {
    document.getElementById('holiday_time_h1').removeAttribute('disabled');
    $('.Timesheet select').removeAttr('disabled'); //ADDED LINE
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Timesheet">
  <span>Opening Time:</span>
  <select id="holiday_time_h1">
    <option>00</option>
  </select>
  :
  <select id="holiday_time_m1">
    <option>00</option>
  </select>

  <span>Closing time</span>
  <select id="holiday_time_h2">
    <option>00</option>
  </select>
  :
  <select id="holiday_time_m2">
    <option>00</option>
  </select>

  <input id="holiday_check" class="check" type="checkbox">Closed</input>

</div>
```

No need of extra code